# Class 'App\' not found post Seeder in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

Hello i'm beginner programer

i building Twitter clone app for Laravel5.4
in reference is　[This](http://medium.com/@just4sky/rebuild-twitter-with-laravel-timeline-2a2b63ca8e1b)

He can use Class App\Tweet.

but i typing terminal `php artisan db:seed --class=TweetTableSeeder`
got error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Tweet' not found
```

i think Declarationed this Class and checking.
i search 1day this error but can't find answer...
please help me

app\tweet.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tweet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'body',
    ];
}
```

ModelFactory.php

```
  <?php
 /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory*/
    $factory->define(App\Tweet::class, function ($faker)
    {
        return [
            'body' => $faker->realText(140),
        ];
    });
```

TweetTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use App\Tweet;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TweetsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Tweet::class, 10)->create([
            'user_id' => 2
        ]);
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(TweetsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should rename `tweet.php` to `Tweet.php`

Comment: thank you  for reply:)  Im fix tweet.php -> Tweet.php, but i got the same error